# Caching Response in MEMORY vs. MyISAM vs. InnoDB

Tags: mysql, caching, innodb, myisam

I need to cache API responses due to a high flood delay. So I will cache **every** response for up to 30 seconds and **whenever I get a cache hit**, I will use the cached data, if it's younger than 30 seconds.

Which storage engine is the best for that?

First thought was **MEMORY**, but it's locking the whole table which I think could make some trouble when many users are online.

Then I thought about **InnoDB**, but then I read that MyISAM is better with many write operations.

But **MyISAM** again locks the whole table.

Which storage engine is best as a API response cache?

Comment: It depends on your setup/your data (e.g. requests/s and cache hit/miss ratio, and if you are < 1000 requests/s, you probably won't see a difference, or it might even work out of the mysql query cache). And you can very easily benchmark this, because all you need to do is changing one word in your code (even while it is running, by an `alter table`). On the other hand, there are tools that work better for caching than a mysql db, you should maybe look into memcache or redis. (Or any other tool, these are just two (popular) examples, without assessment of your requirements.)

Answer (score 1):

*None of the above.*

MySQL is a database, not a cache. The idea is to store data persistently (and in the case of InnoDB, durably). There is no TTL (time to live) or automatic expiration of data in SQL. You would also have to remove data that is older than 30 seconds yourself, or else it would accumulate.

You should use a cache server for data you want to disappear after 30 seconds. Memcached for example allows you to set a TTL in seconds when you set an object in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB.

But...

You say "API responses" -- is that HTML pages?  AJAX replies?  SQL queries?  Something else?

How often is the data changing?  Your design will deliver data that is up to 30 seconds out of date; is that acceptable?  The "Query cache" avoids this, but has other issues.

Have you considered memcached?

What is the overhead of inserting into the proposed cache and checking it every time?  Probably more than the alternatives.

Quite probably you have one or two queries that are a lot slower than they have to be.  Fixing them would eliminate the need for extra caching.  Please `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  We may be able to quickly spot ways to speed them up.